# How to split 1 array into 2 arrays, remove certain items, and combine them again into 1 array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

i want to create something using array. I have 1 array and i need to split it into 2 array. After that search specific items from both array and remove it then combine it 2 array into 1 array.

How do i do that?

I already try to use unset for array but confuse how to use it for specific key since my array data format like 16/2/**1**/1 and 16/2/**1**/5. I need to remove data which have 1.

My format array is like this

```
Array 
( 
[1] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => 16/2/1/1 --> remove this have 1 after 2
        [1] => 16/2/0/2 
        [2] => 16/2/0/3 
        [3] => 16/2/0/4 
        [4] => 16/2/0/5 
        [5] => 16/2/0/6 
        [6] => 16/2/0/7 
        [7] => 16/2/0/8 
        [8] => 16/2/0/9 
        [9] => 16/2/0/10 
        [10] => 16/2/0/11 
        [11] => 16/2/0/12 
        [12] => 16/2/0/13 
        [13] => 16/2/0/14 
        [14] => 16/2/0/15 
        [15] => 16/2/0/16 
    ) 
[2] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => 16/2/0/1 
        [1] => 16/2/0/2 
        [2] => 16/2/0/3 
        [3] => 16/2/0/4 
        [4] => 16/2/1/5 --> and this have 1 after 2 before 5
        [5] => 16/2/0/6 
        [6] => 16/2/0/7 
        [7] => 16/2/0/8 
        [8] => 16/2/0/9 
        [9] => 16/2/0/10 
        [10] => 16/2/0/11 
        [11] => 16/2/0/12 
        [12] => 16/2/0/13 
        [13] => 16/2/0/14 
        [14] => 16/2/0/15 
        [15] => 16/2/0/16 
    ) 
)
```

i expect the output something like (after combine)

```
Array 
   ( 
    [0] => 16/2/0/2 
    [1] => 16/2/0/3 
    [2] => 16/2/0/4 
    [3] => 16/2/0/6 
    [4] => 16/2/0/7 
    [5] => 16/2/0/8 
    [6] => 16/2/0/9 
    [7] => 16/2/0/10 
    [8] => 16/2/0/11 
    [9] => 16/2/0/12 
    [10] => 16/2/0/13 
    [11] => 16/2/0/14 
    [12] => 16/2/0/15 
    [13] => 16/2/0/16 
)
```

Thanks for time to help me.

Comment: Are the array keys indexed or is it just dates, and keys are irrelevant?

Comment: Why do you want to split and you just want to remove ones that have 1` in it? In any position or just 3rd position?

Comment: @Ice76 its not date.. its combined number and yes keys are irrelevant.. its could change with certain condition

Comment: @AbraCadaver if not split up.. it will make double data.. 16/2/0/2 could have 2 record and that could be in any position with certain condition

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: `$array = preg_grep('~^16/2/0/\d+$~', $array)` - Simple  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6361b8995e207eac96673399c51f51e59a4df68)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix could you give more explanation about your answer? thanks

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment, but I added a sandbox link.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks for manual, thats for remove double data.. but how to remove specific data? which have 1 on it?

Comment: _1 on it_ where?  3rd position as in x/x/1/x?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix amazing.. well done.. thats what i mean.. now i need just split the array, using preg_grep.. and combine it again and use array-unique.. thanks all of you for your clue and time...

Comment: @AbraCadaver its done, thanks for your time for giving me clue...

Comment: I don't understand the need for splitting and combining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the array unique and then extract items that are `digits/digits/NOT 1/digits`:

```
$array = preg_grep('#^\d+/\d+/[^1]/\d+#', array_unique($array));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `preg_grep` which allows you to search an array using a Regular expression.

```
$array =[
    '16/2/0/13',
    '16/2/0/16',
    '16/2/1/5'

];

$array = preg_grep('~^16/2/0/\d+$~', $array);

print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16/2/0/13
    [1] => 16/2/0/16
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6361b8995e207eac96673399c51f51e59a4df68)

The Regex

- `^` match start of string
- `16/2/0/` - match literally (at the start of string, see above)
- `\d+` any digit one or more
- `$` match end of string

So Regular expressions is a way to do pattern matching, in this case the pattern is `16/2/0/{n}` where `{n}` is any number.  So by doing this we can find only those items that match that pattern.

Then if you have duplicates, you can do `array_unique()` and easily remove those.

There are many ways to do this `array_filter` with a custom callback etc.  But this is the most straightforward way (if you know Regex).

Comment: Sure, Regex can be very confusing at first, but it's very powerful too.  Good luck!